# Noise in audio out when charging laptop

Tags: sound

I normally use a mini jack cable to connect the audio out of my laptop to my guitar amp to listen to music.

When the computer is on battery I have no problem whatsover with the sound quality. However, the second I plug in the charger to the laptop I get a lot of noise in the guitar amp.

I have Windows 7 on dual boot and this problem doesn't happens there, which allows me to conclude that this is software problem of some sort.

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a Samsung notebook, I couldn't find a solution, So I updated from 9.04 to 10.04. 
The noise while charging was gone. But maybe you should try another thing before doing this, it's a little too drastic ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already am running Ubuntu 11.10, so I guessed the problem would have been fixed by now.. Any other idea?